# Approach to crashed workers in amazon swf

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-swf, aws-ruby-flow

We're currently implementing a workflow in Amazon SWF where we submit jobs/workflow executions from our web application.  Everything was fairly quick and painless to get set up using the Ruby Flow framework.  As long as the deciders/activity workers don't crash we seem to be able to handle most issues/exceptions gracefully.

My question is, what is common practice for the scenario where the decider process crashes midway through a workflow execution?  If the task fails in that way, is it possible to push an SNS notification (I've seen no examples) or something to indicate to another process that there's been an unexpected failure/crash?

Answer (score 1):

There are various types of "decider" failures.

1. Workflow worker crashes while processing a decision. The decision task is automatically rescheduled after specified timeout. Make sure that workflow type [defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RegisterWorkflowType.html#SWF-RegisterWorkflowType-request-defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeout) is not set too high.  If this crash is not related to code correctness then rescheduled task is processed and workflow execution continues normally.
2. Workflow worker doesn't crash but workflow execution itself fails. In this case you can use [ListClosedWorkflowExecutions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ListClosedWorkflowExecutions.html) to count such failed workflows.
3. Workflow worker doesn't crash but a decision task cannot complete as [RespondDecisionTaskCompleted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RespondDecisionTaskCompleted.html) fails due to a bug in the Flow framework. As from SWF point of view task is never completed it at some point is marked as timed out and rescheduled. As bug is still present a new task is again never completes and rescheduled, and so on. The workflow execution that is experiencing such issue has a history with a tail that consists from repeated "decision task scheduled, decision task timed out" events. If your workflow has a known execution time limit then the best way to catch this issue is to set reasonable *executionStartToCloseTimeout* and look for timed out workflow executions. If the decision task timeout is set too low such workflows can also hit the limit on history size before the execution timeout.

Answer (score 0):

All swf metrics are not published to cloud watch. So all completed and failed workflows will send the metrics to cloudwatch where you can create alarms to send you notifications when any workflow fails.